# Using switch in Kendo Grid Client Template

Tags: javascript, c#, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'd like to show different values in a Kendo Grid cell. Something similar to: `"#=IValue ? '1':'0'#"`.

What's the correct syntax to use a switch to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an if/else statement. See [this page](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview).

```
# if (IFlowCode == 1) {# 'A' #} else if (IFlowCode == -1) {# 'b' #} else if (IFlowCode == 0) {# 'C' #}#");
```

Comment: I still get `Invalid template` error. This is my code: `.ClientTemplate("#= if (IFlowCode == 1) {# 'A' #} else if (IFlowCode == -1) {# 'b' #} else if (IFlowCode == 0) {# 'C' #}#");`

Comment: `#=` should be `#` :)

Answer (score 2):

I was finally able to get the switch working in the ClientTemplate :)

`columns.Bound(c => c.HaveNAS).ClientTemplate(@"#var NASVal; switch(HaveNAS){ case 1: NASVal = 'Yes'; break; case 2: NASVal = 'No'; break; case 3: NASVal = 'Probably'; break; default: NASVal = 'Not Sure'; }##=NASVal#")`